# W2012R2 ISCSI MutualAuth: "Initiator CHAP secret given is invalid"

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iscsi

When trying to add a new iSCSI-TargetPortal using the New-IscsiTargetPortal command it simply refuses, telling me the password is not valid and has to be between 12 and 16 bytes.

my command:

```
New-IscsiTargetPortal -TargetPortalAddress "myServer.Domain.Forest" -AuthenticationType MUTUALCHAP -ChapUsername init -ChapSecret NNBGphGAWEYbDyyJ
```

This returns the following error:

> New-IscsiTargetPortal : Initiator CHAP secret given is invalid. Maximum size of CHAP secret is 16 bytes. Minimum size is 12 bytes if IPSec is not used.
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: MSFT_iSCSITargetPortal:ROOT/Microsoft/...CSITargetPortal) [New-IscsiTargetPortal], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0xefff004c,New-IscsiTargetPortal

This when iSCSI target (also win2012R2) accepted the password without any issues, so I have no clue why it's throwing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out. CHAP is not required for discovery.
I did everything again, without the CHAP credentials for discovery and it all worked just fine.